# How can I see a folder's exact size in bytes?

Tags: folder

I have a folder with 40 GB of dozens of directories and stuff, and I want to see the exact size of the root folder in bytes ..

I have tried using this, but it shows the size in kilobytes:

`du -s foldername`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the `-B1` parameter to `du`:

```
du -s -B1 foldername
```

> ```
> $ man 1 du
>  -B, --block-size=SIZE
>           use SIZE-byte blocks
> ```

You could also try the `--apparent-size` flag

Answer (score 8):

du - estimate file space usage

```
-B, --block-size=SIZE
          scale sizes by SIZE before printing them.  E.g., '-BM' prints sizes in units of 1,048,576 bytes.  See SIZE format below.

-b, --bytes
          equivalent to '--apparent-size --block-size=1'
```

For Example,

```
user$ du -B1 filename
```

Answer (score 4):

```
du -sb foldername
```

seems to do the trick

Comment: This gives a different number - did you actually try?

Comment: @guntbert the `-b` flag is shorthand for `-B1 --apparent-size`

Comment: DIfference between "apparent size" and "disk usage space" explains the different numbers